On send my sitemap in the google search console i receive an error Unable to read sitemap
The error in google search console on submit my sitemap path
Unable to read sitemap
Status returned by api: 200
My link from the current sitemap: *https://noticialivre.web.app/sitemap.xml
And my sitemap returned:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
    xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
        <loc>https://noticialivre.web.app</loc>
        <lastmod>2024-08-26T21:18:13+00:00</lastmod>
        <priority>1.00</priority>
        <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://noticialivre.web.app/notice</loc>
        <lastmod>2024-08-26T21:18:13+00:00</lastmod>
        <priority>0.80</priority>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://noticialivre.web.app/politica</loc>
        <lastmod>2024-08-26T21:18:13+00:00</lastmod>
        <priority>0.80</priority>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://noticialivre.web.app/esportes</loc>
        <lastmod>2024-08-26T21:18:13+00:00</lastmod>
        <priority>0.80</priority>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://noticialivre.web.app/militar</loc>
        <lastmod>2024-08-26T21:18:13+00:00</lastmod>
        <priority>1.80</priority>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://noticialivre.web.app/ciencia-e-tecnologia</loc>
        <lastmod>2024-08-26T21:18:13+00:00</lastmod>
        <priority>0.80</priority>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://noticialivre.web.app/economia</loc>
        <lastmod>2024-08-26T21:18:13+00:00</lastmod>
        <priority>0.80</priority>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://noticialivre.web.app/mundo</loc>
        <lastmod>2024-08-26T21:18:13+00:00</lastmod>
        <priority>0.80</priority>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://noticialivre.web.app/previsao-do-tempo</loc>
        <lastmod>2024-08-26T21:18:13+00:00</lastmod>
        <priority>0.80</priority>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://noticialivre.web.app/login</loc>
        <lastmod>2024-08-26T21:18:13+00:00</lastmod>
        <priority>0.00</priority>
        <changefreq>never</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://noticialivre.web.app/cadastro</loc>
        <lastmod>2024-08-26T21:18:13+00:00</lastmod>
        <priority>0.0</priority>
        <changefreq>never</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://noticialivre.web.app/noticia/EQwUnQwUHYY8rTX4A2vE/Mel-alucinogeno-mel-louco-ou-mel-vermelho</loc>
        <lastmod>2024-08-26T21:18:13+00:00</lastmod>
        <priority>1.00</priority>
        <changefreq>never</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://noticialivre.web.app/noticia/TRRtBf4D0MSHxKDqwt0E/Calixcoca---A-vacina-brasileira-que-venceu-premio-internacional</loc>
        <lastmod>2024-08-26T21:18:13+00:00</lastmod>
        <priority>1.00</priority>
        <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://noticialivre.web.app/notice/TRRtBf4D0MSHxKDqwt0E/Calixcoca---A-vacina-brasileira-que-venceu-premio-internacional</loc>
        <priority>1.00</priority>
        <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
        <lastmod>2024-9-15</lastmod>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://noticialivre.web.app/notice/TRRtBf4D0MSHxKDqwt0E/Calixcoca---A-vacina-brasileira-que-venceu-premio-internacional</loc>
        <priority>1.00</priority>
        <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
        <lastmod>2024-9-15</lastmod>
    </url>
</urlset>

I try to submit my sitemap URL from Google Search Console and I was hoping this would work, but I
get an error.
An important information, my system uses hosting from firebase, but the sitemap is returned from the an request from the firebase functions api.
my firebase json:
 {
      "hosting": {
        "site": "noticialivre",
        "source": ".",
        "frameworksBackend": {
          "region": "southamerica-east1"
        },
        "rewrites": [
          {
            "source": "/sitemap.xml",
            "function": {
              "functionId": "sitemap",
              "region": "southamerica-east1"
            }
          },
          {
            "source": "**",
            "destination": "/index.html"
          }
        ]
      }
    }

Detail: My api have a log to register the request data, but my api never is called

I removed my sitemap.xml url and now I'm using an sitemap type html
my new sitemap here:
https://noticialivre.web.app/sitemap
I'm trying to add a sitemap with html extension because the Google bot understands that example links are equal to asdfasdf this makes indexing easier
When i request indexing i receive the error:  'Quota exceeded'
